# Why get/post methods throws Unauthorized (401) ERR?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, express-validator

I have a project for log in and sign up, sign up part i used **Express-Validator** in it, while Log in part I'm using **Passport.JS** but, but when i add passport js deceleration in **app.js** it throws Unauthorized error 401.

**[Postman (Body)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZcVs.png)**

**app.js (Lines that causes the problem)**

> These two lines of code causes this poblem, when i *Comment Them* it works but in this case i will not able to using *Passport.js*

```
//passport
app.use(passport.authorize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**app.js (All lines of code)**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const passport = require('passport');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//session
app.use(session({
  secret : 'Thisis a big secret :-)',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}));

//flash
app.use(flash())

//passport
app.use(passport.authorize());
app.use(passport.session()); 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

////////////////////// DB connecting /////////////////////////////
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/product', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, res)=>{
  (err)?console.log('ERR While connecting to DB => ' + err):console.log('DB is connected successfully...');
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const product = require('../model/product');
const users = require('../model/users');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const passport = require('passport');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  product.find({}, (err, doc)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log('ERR while searching in DB =>' + err);
    }
      var grid = 3;
      var arr = [];
      for(var i = 0; i<doc.length; i+=grid){
        arr.push(doc.slice(i , i+grid));
      }
      console.log(arr)

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', product : arr });
  })

});

/* router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

}); */
//GET login
router.get('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
  res.render('login')

});
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash: true,
}));

router.get('/signup', function (req, res, next){
  const msg = req.flash('error')
  res.render('signup', {messages : msg});
});
router.post('/signup',  [
    // password must be at least 5 chars long
    check('password').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('Please enter Password with more than 5 letters!'),
    // username must be an email
    check('username').not().isNumeric().withMessage('please fill username with STRING only'),
    // password must be at least 5 chars long
    check('email').not().isEmpty().withMessage('please fill email with STRING only'),
    check('email').not().isEmail().withMessage('please enter valid email'),
    // password must be at least 5 chars long
    check('password').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Please fill password fie'),
    check('repassword').custom((val, {req})=>{
      if(val !== req.body.password){
        throw new Error('Password is not equal to confirm password');
      }
      return true;
    })
  ],
  function (req, res, next){

    // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      var validationMessage = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<errors.errors.length; i++){
      validationMessage.push(errors.errors[i].msg);
    }
    req.flash('error', validationMessage)
      res.redirect('signup')
    }

    const newUser = new users({
      username : req.body.username,
      password : new users().hashPassword(req.body.password)
    });
    users.findOne({username : req.body.username}, (err, doc)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log('ERR while getting username =>' + err);
        return ;
      }
      if(doc){
        console.log('this email is already exist')
      }
    });
    newUser.save((err, doc)=>{
      if(!err){
        console.log('err')
      }else{
        console.log('ERR in saving users =>' + err);
      }
    })
});


module.exports = router;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "market",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "hbs": "~4.0.4",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's happening because you are applying the authorize middleware to every route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank you all, *answer :*
>
> **app.js ( Two lines causes the problem) have to be:**

**From**

```
//passport
app.use(passport.authorize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**To**

```
//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the authorize Middleware only to your private routes.